# Twofold Hashed Password Authentication with Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish

I have an application that requires passwords to be hashed two fold, lets call hash function A and B.

Normally authentication is done with glassfish, which uses a "disgests-function", implying all password given by users will be hashed with this function and verify with database.

How can i set it up so users password in request will be hashed by two functions A and B ? Should i write a custom authentication module ?

Comment: Yes, you should write a custom authentication module!

Comment: I follow this Tutorial : http://x-techteam.blogspot.de/2008/03/glassfish-login-module-simple-example.html  and couldnt find where the password is compared with input, or how should i write my custom module ? Where does he find the _username Variable ?

Comment: There is no username + password authentication in the tutorial you linked. Did you read the text of the tutorial?